# Как мне скрыть из layout widget до тех пор пока не запустится анимация?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qlayout

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
import sys
import os                                                            # +++

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))                # +++

#Or

'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect
'''

class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(test_mynu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!
        #------menu_pos_block------
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(maximumWidth=30, minimumWidth=0)
        #self.menu_pos_block.setGeometry(QRect(40, 20, 0, 0))
    
        blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=5)
        self.menu_pos_block.setGraphicsEffect(blur)
        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------menu_block------
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)             ######
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")
        
        menu_layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        self.menu_by_pos = None

        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_pos_block = test_mynu("menu_{}".format(i))
            menu_pos_block.setObjectName("menu_pos_{}".format(i))

            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)
            self.menu_pos[i].setGeometry(QRect(menu_pos_block.width(), menu_pos_block.height(), 151, 181))
            menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[i])

        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)             ######
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(i))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("{}".format(i))
            menu_but_radio.toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)

            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(menu_but_radio)

        # conect menu and but
        self.menu_by_but = dict()
        self.but_by_menu = dict()
        for i in range(self.num()):
            but = self.menu_but[i]
            menu = self.menu_pos[i]

            self.menu_by_but[menu] = but
            self.but_by_menu[but] = menu

        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)             ######
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)

        self.num = 0
        self.menu_pos_ter = []

    def menu_animation(self):
        self.num =self.num+1
        self.toggle_animations.clear()

        num = int(self.sender().objectName())
        self.menu_pos_ter.append(self.menu_pos[num])

        #retutn element с _expand = True
        for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos_ter, key=lambda x: x._expand):
            menu_width = 74 #menu.width()
            menu_height = 81#menu.height()
            
            menu.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
            
            pos1 = QRect( self.menu_block_but.x() - menu_width, menu.y(),menu_width,menu_height)
            pos2 = QRect( self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), menu.y(),menu_width,menu_height)
            pos3 = QRect(menu.width(),menu.height(), menu.x(), menu.y())

            anims = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"maximumWidth")
            anims.setDuration(1000)
            anims.setStartValue(30)
            anims.setEndValue(100)
    
            print(menu.width())
            print(menu.height())
            print("--x--")
            print( menu.x())
            print( menu.y())
            
            but = self.menu_by_but[menu]
            menu.raise_()
            self.menu_block_but.raise_()
            if but.isChecked():

                start_pos = pos1
                end_pos = pos2
            else:
                start_pos = pos2
                end_pos = pos1

            anim = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"geometry")
            anim.setDuration(1000)
            anim.setStartValue(start_pos)
            anim.setEndValue(end_pos)

            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(anim)
            
            self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(anims)
            self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(self.toggle_animations)
            
        if (self.num == 1) or (self.num == 3):
            self.toggle_animation.start()
            self.menu_pos_ter.clear()

        if self.num == 3 :
            self.num = 1
        print("--x--")


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    
    #load qml
    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "qml_window.qml")                     # +++
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)                                     # +++
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load(url)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(engine.rootObjects()[0])
    w = MainWindow(widget)
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

При нажатии на `radio` widget улетает в бок, а место, которое он занимал остается. 
Я `хочу скрыть widget за границы layout родителя` и при нажатии `radio` выдвигать его. 
Но проблема в том, что `я не могу менять размер widgets внутри layout` команду:

```
   self.menu_pos_block.setGeometry(QRect(40, 20, 0, 0))
```

он не воспринимает, а если я добавляю:

```
   self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(maximumWidth=0, minimumWidth=0)
```

то уже:

```
   QRect( self.menu_block_but.x() - menu_width, menu.y(),menu_width,menu_height)
```

не реагирует на мои команды.

---

Еще раз уточняю что до включения `radio` весь `widget` должен выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а уже после нажатия кнопки выдвигаться из границ `layout` родителя в нужную сторону:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тяжелый код. Чтобы немного понять, что происходит, 
я отключил `app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)` и 
установил в некоторых местах `setStyleSheet`, чтобы видеть где-какой виджет.

Убрал `menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[i])`, 
т.к. управлять геометрией в макете не возможно.

Обратите внимание на расчет `pos1` и `pos2` 
и др. отмеченное в тексте.

Пробуйте.

```
import sys
import os                                                            
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt, QPropertyAnimation)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow,\
     QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))               


#class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
class Test_Menu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(Test_Menu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False      
        self.setStyleSheet('background:#0f0; color:#000;')                        # + уберете      
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(maximumWidth=30, minimumWidth=0)
        blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=1)                        # 5 установите свое
        self.menu_pos_block.setGraphicsEffect(blur)
        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
#        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr[-2:])                                     # установите свое
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def num(self):
        return 3

    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
        self.toggle_animation  = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(objectName="centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget, objectName="central_w_layout")
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.block.setObjectName(u"block")

        self.x, self.y = 166, 205                                             # +
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.start_x_y)                         # +++

        self.block.setStyleSheet('background:#f99; color:#00f;')              # + уберете 
        central_w_layout.addWidget(self.block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             

        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.block)
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        menu_block.setStyleSheet('background:#ff9; color:#0ff;')              # + уберете 
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)                         
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")
        menu_layout.setSpacing(10)                                            # 0 установите свое

        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        self.menu_by_pos = None

        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_pos_block = Test_Menu("menu_{}".format(i), self)              # + , self !!!
            menu_pos_block.setObjectName("menu_pos_{}".format(i))
            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)

# -           self.menu_pos[i].setGeometry(QRect(menu_pos_block.width(), menu_pos_block.height(), 151, 181))            
            self.menu_pos[i].setGeometry(QRect(-10, -10, 0, 0))                # + 
            self.menu_pos[i].show()                                            # +

#            menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[i])                           # ---

        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)         
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(i))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("{}".format(i))
            menu_but_radio.toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)
            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(menu_but_radio)

        # conect menu and but
        self.menu_by_but = dict()
        self.but_by_menu = dict()
        for i in range(self.num()):
            but = self.menu_but[i]
            menu = self.menu_pos[i]
            self.menu_by_but[menu] = but
            self.but_by_menu[but] = menu

        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)     
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)

        self.num = 0
        self.menu_pos_ter = []
        self.menu_nums = []                                                  # +++

    def menu_animation(self):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        self.toggle_animations.clear()
        num = int(self.sender().objectName())
        self.menu_pos_ter.append(self.menu_pos[num])

        #retutn element с _expand = True
        for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos_ter, key=lambda x: x._expand):
            menu_width  = 74    # menu.width()
            menu_height = 81    # menu.height()
            menu.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))

            if self.menu_nums:                                                   # +
                self.menu_nums = [self.menu_nums[-1],]                           # +
            self.menu_nums.append(menu)                                          # +

            pos1 = QRect(self.x,               #self.menu_block_but.x() - menu_width, 
                         self.y,               #menu.y(),
                         menu_width,
                         menu_height)

            pos2 = QRect(self.x+200,           #self.menu_block_but.x() + self.menu_block_but.width(), 
                         self.y,               # menu.y(),
                         menu_width,
                         menu_height)
# ???            pos3 = QRect(menu.width(), menu.height(), menu.x(), menu.y())

            anims = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"maximumWidth")
            anims.setDuration(1000)
            anims.setStartValue(30)
            anims.setEndValue(100)

            but = self.menu_by_but[menu]
            menu.raise_()
            self.menu_block_but.raise_()
            if but.isChecked():
                start_pos = pos1
                end_pos = pos2
            else:
                start_pos = pos2
                end_pos = pos1

            anim = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"geometry")
            anim.setDuration(1000)
            anim.setStartValue(start_pos)
            anim.setEndValue(end_pos)
            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(anim)
#?            self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(anims)                      # - ???
            self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(self.toggle_animations)

        if (self.num == 1) or (self.num == 3): 
            self.toggle_animation.start()
            self.menu_pos_ter.clear()
        if self.num == 3 :
            self.num = 1        

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
    def start_x_y(self):
        self.x, self.y = self.block.x()-100, self.block.y()+20

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.x, self.y = self.block.x()-100, self.block.y()+20
        [ i.move(-100, 0) for i in self.menu_pos]
        for i, menu in enumerate(reversed(self.menu_nums)):
            if i == 0: menu.move(self.x+200, self.y)
            else: menu.move(self.x, self.y)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                 # !!! установите

    #load qml
    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "qml_window.qml") 
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)                  
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load(url)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(engine.rootObjects()[0])
    w = MainWindow(widget)
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я попробовал удалить lay из test_mynu и заменить в строках `38:self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self) 39:self.menu_pos_block.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 75, 80))` Удевительно но это помогло. Спасибо